# show weights beside performancepoint KPIs

Tags: sdk, dashboard, performancepoint, kpi

I have a client who has requested that the weights given to each KPI be shown on the Performancepoint dashboard.

How can i do this? Does the SDK allow for such?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After adding the KPI to the scorecard, add your Score Rollup Weight as normal.  Right-click on the Target column, and select Properties.  Check Show Score under Scoring.  Your weight will now be displayed next to the indicator in the Target column.